# How can I get the right click event object file name?

Tags: c++, windows, com, atl, explorer

I created a ATL/COM project, and implement the IShellExtInit interface. In the Initialize method, I use the DrapDropFile function to get the file names of the files whose selected in the folder.

e.g.

1.In the folder C:\WINDOWS\MyFolder\ contains the files:

```
a.png, b.bmp, c.jpg
```

2.Right click the "b.bmp".

3.In the Initialize method, I get a list of file names.

```
fileNames[0] = C:\WINDOWS\MyFolder\b.bmp

fileNames[1] = C:\WINDOWS\MyFolder\c.jpg

fileNames[2] = C:\WINDOWS\MyFolder\a.png
```

Question:

How can I get the actual sequence of the file.( a/b/c not b/c/a )

Expect:

1.Right click the "b.bmp".

```
I get the file name: C:\WINDOWS\MyFolder\a.png
```

2.Right click the "a.png".

```
I get the file name: C:\WINDOWS\MyFolder\a.png
```

Comment: You get the files in whatever order the source fills the IDataObject; short of performing your own sorting on the target end, I don't think you can do anything about it.

Comment: I need the actual clicked object.

Comment: I thought explorer passed the selected object in as the first item in the IDataObject (been a while, so I could be wrong).  In any event, I don't think there is a straightforward way to do this.  The only thing I can think of is to try to find the IShellFolderView (or whatever) of the relevant folder and trying to determine the focused object in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

The item that was clicked on is always first.  The order of the remaining items is undefined and non-deterministic.